# How to properly use a toString method?

Tags: java, tostring

So I'm getting a head start on my Computer Science Lab project, basically we're creating an activity time tracker. The goal of this program is to enter minutes, and seconds into the console, and the program will take these values, and print the total time, repeating the process until the user enters an invalid number in which the program will terminate.

Much of the ActivityManager class was finished, and created by the professor, with only a few lines needing to be changed, and indicated with a comment.

Here is that class:

```
{
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    // declare totalTime and activityTime of type Itime 
    Itime totalTime, activityTime;
    int minutes; double seconds; // user input values
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in); // to read user input

    // display purpose and author
    System.out.println ("This program tracks total time in minutes");  
    System.out.println ("and seconds for a series of activities."); 
    System.out.println ();  // print blank line
    System.out.println ("Author: ");
    System.out.println ();  // print blank line 

    // specify format for input 
    System.out.println ("Enter activity time in minutes and" 
        + " seconds, all in a");   
    System.out.println ("single line with spaces in between.  Entering" 
        + " values" ); 
    System.out.println ("outside appropriate ranges will terminate"
        + " the program."); 
    System.out.println ();  // print blank line

    // create the totalTime object of type Itime with 0 minutes and 0.0 seconds
    totalTime = new Itime(0,0.0);
    System.out.println ("Total time so far is: "
        + totalTime.toString()); 
    System.out.println ();  // print blank line

    // prompt and read time for an activity 
    System.out.print ("Enter time for an activity: ");   
    minutes = input.nextInt(); 
    seconds = input.nextDouble();

    // Accumulate if appropriate 
    while (minutes >= 0 && seconds >= 0 && seconds < 60) {
        // create the activityTime object of type Itime with given minutes and seconds
        activityTime = new Itime(minutes,seconds);
        // add totalTime and activityTime and put the result in totalTime
        totalTime = totalTime.addItime(activityTime);      
        System.out.println ("Total time so far is: "
            + totalTime.toString()); 
        System.out.println ();  // print blank line

        // prompt and read time for another activity
        System.out.print ("Enter time for an activity: ");   
        minutes = input.nextInt(); 
        seconds = input.nextDouble(); 
    }

    // wrap up and print final total
    System.out.println ("Sentinel received"); 
    System.out.println ();  // print blank line 
    System.out.println ("Total time so far is: "
        + totalTime.toString()); 
System.out.println ();  // print blank line

    // print closing remarks
    System.out.println ("Program has terminated."); 
    System.out.println ();  // print blank line 
}
```

We were tasked with finishing the project by creating an Itime class, which is here:

```
{
private int minutes;
private double seconds;
public Itime(int minutes, double seconds){
    assert(minutes >= 0 && seconds >= 0 && seconds < 60);
}
public int getMinutes(){return minutes;}
public double getSeconds(){return seconds;}
public String toString(){
Itime totalTime = new Itime(minutes, seconds);
    String toString=this.minutes +" minutes and "+this.seconds+" seconds";
return toString;}
public Itime addItime(Itime bTime){
    int totalMinutes = this.minutes+bTime.getMinutes();
    double totalSeconds =  this.seconds+bTime.getSeconds();
    if(totalSeconds>60){
    totalSeconds-=60;
    totalMinutes+=1;
    }
    Itime totalTime = new Itime(totalMinutes,totalSeconds);
    return totalTime;
}
```

My issue with this project is that no matter what values I enter, it returns the default starting value of 0 minutes, and 0.0 seconds. Originally I believed my issue was the addItime method, but after reviewing the code I believe the issue lies within the toString method.

The console prints out the following:

This program tracks total time in minutes
and seconds for a series of activities.

Author:     Version: January 25, 2019

Enter activity time in minutes and seconds, all in a
single line with spaces in between.  Entering values
outside appropriate ranges will terminate the program.

Total time so far is: 0 minutes and 0.0 seconds

Enter time for an activity: 20 20

Total time so far is: 0 minutes and 0.0 seconds

Enter time for an activity:

Any suggestions?

Comment: Voted to close this question as a typo. And I'll give you a hint: really think about what your `Itime` constructor does. It is missing some stuff.

Comment: As a beginner, debuging code that you write to find errors is an important skill to develop. I suggest that you start by reading https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ for some tips and tricks.

Comment: You never assign to `minutes` or `seconds` in your `Itime` class.

Comment: .toString() is NOT broken!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow. (I'm saying this because I think this is your first time using it, since you annexed in the question description all the code you had. For future questions try to focus only on the code where you think the problem lies. Anyway, I hope you like our community).

Now let's focus in here:

```
public String toString() {
    Itime totalTime = new Itime(minutes, seconds);
    String toString=this.minutes +" minutes and "+this.seconds+" seconds";
    return toString;
}
```

First of all, you don't need to create another instance of the class `Itime` because you already have access to the variables inside the `toString()` method. Also, this method isn't broken; it's working fine.

Now, check out the constructor:

```
public Itime(int minutes, double seconds) {
    assert(minutes >= 0 && seconds >= 0 && seconds < 60);
}
```

You are never assigning `minutes` or `seconds` to an instance of `ITime` class. That's why when you try to try to print out any given instance (through console I might guess), you are always going to get default values (zeros) as a result.

The constructor should look more like this:

```
public Itime(int minutes, double seconds) {
    assert(minutes >= 0 && seconds >= 0 && seconds < 60);
    this.minutes = minutes;
    this.seconds = seconds;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you so much! In the assignment he gave to us, he told us to use assert. Having previously completed a lab with an assert which worked, I copied the code. Thanks for the help!

Comment: assert is used more in JUnit for testing purposes for example. I'm glad it was helpful :D. Enjoy coding.

Comment: the `assert` command is unrelated to JUnit; JUnit use `assert*()` methods like `assertEquals()`

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger okay, thank you for the explanation.

Comment: no problem [:-)  Puerta del Sol, Gran Via, Paseo Rosales, ... muchos recuerdos de Madrid  - abrazos